# Simple prototype using react html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am new to react am trying to write a simple menu functionality.

When I click **choice A** the heading content should be replaced by **choice A** and show its lists. Similarly when I click **choice B** the **choice A** should be replaced by **choice B** and list down its nested list value.

Right now I am able to render the html values but not sure how to proceed. Need help :(

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMRVJd**

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      active: false
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    alert("123");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div className ="heading-conatiner">Heading container </div>
        <ul>
            <li onClick={this.handleClick} className="main-list">Choice A
              <ul className= "sub-list">
                <li>Sub 1--Choice A</li>
                <li>Sub 2---Choice A</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li onClick={this.handleClick} className="main-list">Choice B
              <ul className= "sub-list">
                <li>Sub 1--Choice B</li>
                <li>Sub 2--Choice B</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Search />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the `.heading-container` to contain the `sub-list` items from the menu choice you click on?

Comment: @RobM. thanks for your reply...the heading-conatiner should contain both the main-list and sub-list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to store your menu items in state,

```
this.state = {
  menu: 'Heading Content',
  menus: {
    a: ['Sub 1 - Choice A', 'Sub 2 - Choice A'],
    b: ['Sub 1 - Choice B', 'Sub 2 - Choice B']
  }
}
```

signify in some way that the click on an item ties to a specific menu, either with a `data-` attribute or more functionally:

```
handleClick(menu) {
  return (event) => {
    const selectedMenu = this.state.menus[menu];
    this.setState({
      menu: (
       <ul>{
          menu.map((item) => {
            return <li>{item}</li>;
          })
       }</ul>
    });
  };
}
```

Update your click handlers like so:

```
<li onClick={this.handleClick('a')} className="main-list">Choice A
```

Then have your header display state rather than a string (which will require you to do some innerHTML tomfoolery):

```
<div className ="heading-conatiner">{this.state.menu}</div>
```

Here is an updated codepen that could definitely be improved upon quite a bit: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKZNVP

Comment: M thank you  so much, it should show with Choice A...now its showing `Sub 1 - Choice A
Sub 2 - Choice A` alone....is it anyway can we modify so that we can show all the three

Comment: Nice, Rob I went down a very similar route when working this out. I think it is important to note how the data is following through the application!

Comment: @texirv yes, totally possible. I would just switch from hardcoded menus to totally dynamic http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKZNVP

Comment: @rob m is it too to write mocha test cases in our cidepen itself

Comment: @RobM. I am trying to implement sliding functionality on top of it....so that the value changes with a slide from right to left...any idea about slide...never used slide before :(

Answer (score 1):

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      active: false,
      choice: 'A'
    }
  }

  handleClick(choice) {
    this.setState({choice: choice })
  }

  render() {
    var choices = this.props.choices[this.state.choice].map(function(e, i){
      return (<li key={i}>{e}</li>);
    });

    return (
      <div class="wrapper">

        <div className="heading-conatiner">
            <ul className="sub-list">
                {choices}
              </ul>
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,'A')} className="main-list">Choice A

            </li>
            <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,'B')} className="main-list">Choice B

            </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
var choices = {
  A: ['choiceA1', 'choiceA2'],
  B: ['choiceB1', 'choiceB2']
}
React.render(<Search choices={choices}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Consider passing the choices as props to the component. Maybe store the current selection, or choice, in state.Check it here, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeGmqR

Comment: I was going to have the menus be props but just went for the minimum viable product :P, this is probably a better setup (as opposed to hardcoding into state) as you get a flexible reusable component. Nice!